# How to access each pixel value of RGB image?

Tags: opencv, rgb, at-command, mat

I am trying to read RGB image. However, I can only access with Vec3b type, not each channel.
I am sure what is the problem. Would like to help me out of misery?

```
imgMod = imread("rgb.png");

for (int iter_x = 0; iter_x < imgMod.cols; ++iter_x)
{
    for (int iter_y = 0; iter_y < imgMod.rows; ++iter_y)
    {
        cout << imgMod.at<cv::Vec3b>(iter_y, iter_x) << "\t";
        cout << imgMod.at<cv::Vec3b>(iter_y, iter_x)[0] << "\t";
        cout << imgMod.at<cv::Vec3b>(iter_y, iter_x)[1] << "\t";
        cout << imgMod.at<cv::Vec3b>(iter_y, iter_x)[2] << endl;
    }
}
```

Here is a result for pixel value of RGB image.

```
[153, 88, 81]          X     Q
[161, 94, 85]    。    ^     T
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your access is fine.
The type returned by the `[]` operator is `char` so the value gets printed as a `char` - a text character. Just cast it to `int` to see the grey value as an integer:

```
cout << int(imgMod.at<cv::Vec3b>(iter_y, iter_x)[0]) << "\t";
```

A (more readable and explicit) C++ way to do it would be this:

```
static_cast<int>(imgMod.at<cv::Vec3b>(iter_y, iter_x)[0]) << "\t";
```

Even more cool is this [(obscure?) little trick](http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/09/tippet-printing-numeric-values-for-chars-and-uint8_t/) - note the `+`:

```
cout << +imgMod.at<cv::Vec3b>(iter_y, iter_x)[0] << "\t";
//      ^
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. By the way, does it have any differece between int(imgMod.at<cv::Vec3b>(iter_y, iter_x)[0]) and (int)imgMod.at<cv::Vec3b>(iter_y, iter_x)[0] ??

Comment: Cool, then you can mark the answer as answered. I'm not sure there would be a difference. The (more readable and explicit) C++ way to do it would be this: `static_cast<int>(imgMod.at<cv::Vec3b>(iter_y, iter_x)[0])`.

Comment: @HojungJung: If the problem is resolved, please mark the question as answered :-).